# Removing last line and initial whitespaces from an 8 by 8 list of integers in python

Tags: python, list

```
#Print the user board 

s = ''
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        z = i * n + j
        s += ' '
        if z < 10:
            s += ' '
        s += str(z)
    s += '\n'
print(dedent(s))

queens = list(map(int, input("Queens: ").split()))
```

I keep getting an error from my testcase environment of a last blank line before proceeding to the queens input below. What can I approach to fix

I have tried cleandoc from textwrap and while it works, it disrupts every required spacing and new distinctive lines for z from the "s" string which is a perfect 8 by 8 from 0 to 63.

Comment: What is your expected output? What does `dedent` do? When I use `n=8` and remove `dedent` I get a perfectly squared 8 by 8 grid

Comment: dedent attempts to remove the initial whitespaces from the lines. removing dedent prints the perfect matrix but creates initial whites spaces. check below

0 1 2 (with dedent)
#initial tabspace 0 1 2 (without dedent)

Comment: Do you mean the whitespaces that only occur for the numbers below 10? That is what you're doing in your if statement

Comment: No, white spaces occur in all the 7 rows without dedent....I want to eliminate those 7 whitespaces. The if statement moves the numbers below 0-9 to the right( right justified) only

Comment: If this is the accepted answer than the question is not the one in the title. Title should be adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the right way instead of removing things after is easier:

```py
from itertools import count
import toolz

n = 8
start_value = 0
counter = count(start_value)
rows = [" ".join(f"{num:2}" for num in toolz.take(n, counter)) for _ in range(n)]
print("\n".join(rows))
```

The [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) creates an iterable counter that gives the next value every time you want. Here the [`take`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.take) function will get 8 items each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the initial space, you'd better use `join`, which only adds the *separator* between consecutive items:

```
s = '\n'.join(' '.join('{:2d}'.format(i * n + j)
                       for j in range(n))
              for i in range(n))
print(s)
```

gives as expected:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
```